# Displaying the error message If any error occured in the TryUpdateModel in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My Code :-

```
if (TryUpdateModel(model))
{
    //My Logic
}           
else
{
    ActivityLogger.LogActivity("HandleReceiverAddressSubmitted Method" + ModelState.Values); 
}
```

Here in `ModelState.Values`, rather then giving the actual error message, its showing as

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection'

Could you please help me how do I log the error message if any error occurred in the `TryUpdateModel`.

Comment: You need to check each property in `ModelState` - for example `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` will give you the property name and associated error message (and you can then build a string from that)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the `Error` messages like this

```
var messages = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(s=>s.Errors).Select(g=>g.ErrorMessage);
```

Here `messages` will be an `IEnumerable<string>`. You can use `string.Join` to get a single comma separated string from that

```
var messagesJoined = string.Join(",", messages);
ActivityLogger.LogActivity("HandleReceiverAddressSubmitted Method" + messagesJoined );
```